# NullPointerException on HashMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<Integer, JButton>`. The problem is when I try to retrieve a value I get `null`, not a JButton. The exception occurs when I try to add "butt" to centerPanel in the last line. Below is a snippet of my code an 2 class fields to put the code into perspective.

```
public class GUI {

private JPanel centerPanel;
private JButton button;
private JLabel label;
private Image source;
private Image image;
private HashMap<Integer, JButton> images = new HashMap<>();

public GUI() {

    centerPanel = new JPanel();

    ImageIcon sid = new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("koala.jpg"));
    source = sid.getImage();


    int ind = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            if ( j == 2 && i == 3) {
                label = new JLabel("");
                centerPanel.add(label);
            } else {
                button = new JButton();
                button.addActionListener(this);
                images.put(new Integer(++ind), button);
                image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                    new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/4, 
                        (width/3)+1, height/4)));
                button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            }
        }
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
        Integer numb = new Integer(random.nextInt(images.size()));
        JButton butt = images.get(1);
        centerPanel.add(butt);
        images.remove(numb);
    }

    setSize(1024, 768);
    setTitle("Puzzle");
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
}  
}
```

Why does the NullPointerException occur? I'm aware I don't need to explicitly create Integers.

Comment: Is there any relation between `ind` and `images.size()`?

Comment: Provide an SSCCE. Witht the posted code, we can only guess. And print the keys stored in the map, and the key used when trying to get a value from the map, to see what could be wrong. Also check that the map is the same object in both places. Traces are your friend. The debugger is your best friend.

Comment: Yes. Whenever I put a mapping into images, I assume that images.size will also inrease?

Comment: Did anyone else giggle when you saw a variable named "butt"?

Comment: Alright, I can see that incomplete code would cause some problems. I included the entire class.

Comment: Yes, I truly believe the debugger could become my friend. But I've never worked with any IDEs :(. I tried accessing values in images manually with 0 and 1. NullPointer

Comment: I commented out the line producing NullPointer and made the main method `System.out.println(images.entrySet());` which produces a huge cluster of the JButtons and all their attributes. Conclusion: They're properly added to images. Why can't I retrieve them?

Comment: A) If your keys are ascending int indexes why using HashMap and not a List? B) Since you use ++ind, your first ind will be 1. The range of your random starts at zero. And also, as noted below, your random range is successive and when removing items from the map your keys range isn't...

Comment: @amotzg That is a very good question, and I'm surprised I can't answer it. Because I specifically changed it from an ArrayList to HashMap after I encountered a problem. Logical error :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer numb = new Integer(random.nextInt(images.size()));
JButton butt = images.get(1);
centerPanel.add(butt);
images.remove(numb);
```

On one iteration `numb` will be equal to 1 (this can occur on any iteration, as you retrieve a random number between 0 and images.size(), and this is guaranteed to occur, since `images.size()` decreases from 11 to 1), so element under index 1 will be removed. On next iteration `images.get(1)` returns `null`. Then you attempt `centerPanel.add(butt);` and get an NPE.

Comment: Yeah, I see. What a stupid mistake.. I just translated the code from an ArrayList to HashMap and thought I was still working with indexes. What a stupid mistake =/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SSCCE

```
@Test
public void mapNPE() {

    Map<Integer, String> images = new HashMap<>();
    int ind = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if ( j == 2 && i == 3) {
                System.out.println("j == 2 && i == 3");
            } else {
                images.put(new Integer(++ind), Integer.toString(i) + "," + Integer.toString(j));
            }
        }
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
        Integer numb = new Integer(random.nextInt(images.size()));
        System.out.println(numb);
        if(numb == 1) {
            System.out.println("Image will be removed, next iteration will get null from map");
        }
        String butt = images.get(1);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(i) + "=" + butt);
        images.remove(numb);
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
j == 2 && i == 3
4
0=0,0
3
1=0,0
3
2=0,0
8
3=0,0
5
4=0,0
1
Image will be removed, next iteration will get null from map
5=0,0
5
6=null
3
7=null
1
Image will be removed, next iteration will get null from map
8=null
4
9=null
5
10=null
```

I guess now you get why you **randomly** get a NPE